# Foreign Key contraints with AWS RDS not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to move my local laravel database up to RDS, I have had lots of problems with Elastic beanstalk so I decided to go a different way. When I migrate I get the following error with every foreign key I have:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
>   1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `videos` add
>   constraint `videos_object_id_foreign` foreign key   (`object_id`)
>   references `objects` (`id`) on delete cascade)

**PDOException**

```
[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

I have looked into RDS's foreign key constraints and they say they are not enforced, but it says they can be used for informational purposes.
Every foreign key is unsigned.

```
Schema::create('videos', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('object_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('object_id')->references('id')->on('objects')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Note: I have also tried separated the forein keys into a separate migration after the table was created and had no luck.

Comment: Which migration comes first? `videos` or `objects`? It might be because you still don't have your `objects` table and you are trying to create a reference with that.

Answer (score 1):

To find the specific error run this:

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
```

And look in the `LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR` section.

The data type for the child column must match the parent column exactly.

Also, you should run the query `set foreign_key_checks=0` before running the DDL so you can create the tables in an arbitrary order rather than needing to create all parent tables before the relevant child tables.